# How do I set depthimage resolution

Tags: ros, resolution

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This must be simple to do, how do I set the resolution of a depthimage? For some reason my xtion is publishing 120x160 pixles. I'm using:

rosrun openni2_camera openni2_camera_node

To start the process (roslaunch isn't working for me unfortunately )

Many Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191642/how-do-i-set-depthimage-resolution/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2014-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Answer Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/191468/xtion-depth-image-size-problem/?answer=191687#post-id-191687)

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1